# Setting CopyFeatures_management output to newly created folder in Python script?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

How do I set the output of the copyfeatures_management so that the shapefiles go into the new folder I created?  Currently, they are being placed in my set workspace at the beginning of my code.

```
outFolder = "path"
outName = "TractBuffer_Intersect_D"

arcpy.CreateFolder_management(outFolder, outName)

fcA = "Distance_Buffer.shp"
fcB = "tracts.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcB, "layerfcB")

desc = arcpy.Describe(fcA)
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName
i = 0

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fcA) 
for row in cursor:
    i=i+1
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("layerfcB", "intersect", row.getValue(shapefieldname))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("layerfcB", "output_path"+str(i)+ ".shp")
del cursor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this is what you're meaning, see the outFolder variable below.  Also the 'enumerate' function is real nice instead of doing i=0, i=i+1

```
pth = "path"
outName = "TractBuffer_Intersect_D"
outFolder = arcpy.CreateFolder_management(pth, outName)[0]
fcA = "Distance_Buffer.shp" 
fcB = "tracts.shp"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcB, "layerfcB")
shapefieldname = arcpy.Describe(fcA).ShapeFieldName 

for i, row in enumerate(arcpy.SearchCursor(fcA), 1): 
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("layerfcB", "intersect", row.getValue(shapefieldname))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("layerfcB", outFolder + "\\" + str(i) + ".shp")

del row
```